# Wrong shape with proportional editing

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I'm currently trying to bend this plane around a corner:

[image: A flat and shaped plane]

I turned on Proportional Editing and moved the rightmost vertex on the Y-axis:

[image: The plane being bent around a corner]

This creates a problem. The arc that is created goes in the wrong direction. I want it to confine to the correct arc that I drew:

[image: Notes showing the wrong arc and the wanted arc]

This looks like the kind of shape I want (taken from a UV Sphere):

[image: My ideal shape]

I've already tried manually dragging the individual parts of the arc to the correct places, but it makes the arc look really artificial and rough (which is not ideal, considering that the model I'm making is supposed to be organic and natural-looking). I have tried different falloffs, but those did not work either. I also tried moving the center of the arc to the correct place with Proportional Editing turned on, but it also results in a very weird looking shape.

How would I go about solving this? I would prefer it if the solution used Proportional Editing, but I do not mind if there is a more efficient solution that does not use Proportional Editing.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are after.  Can you show what shape you want?

Comment: @TreyHarper Alright, I edited in a picture of the shape I want. Please let me know if it's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *Sharp* profile.
It's the only one that bends 'inwards'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver! This issue was pretty hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the side profile of the shape, solidify and then add a screw modifier set to 360

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering! I do not want to make the shape circular or a screw-like. I want to just bend the arc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender Stack Exchange :). Please consider adding some images to your answer, so it's easier to understand.